# Installing a wildcard SSL Cert

Tags: security-certificate

I am in the process of putting the final touches to a rather complex multi-server setup where the server domain names are along the lines of srva.example.com, srvb.example.com etc.  At present I have four servers but that number will grow.  I have done a lot to keep my admin burden to a bare minimum and want to ensure that stays the case with providing SSL access to the servers.  With that in mind what I want do do is this

- Complete the server configuration for srva.example.com by installing a wildcard SSL cert.  They seem to be reasonably cheap these days.  My servers do not do any e-commerce so I do not need much by way of certificte - the one I am looking at is from an outfit called Comodo.
- Get an image of srva.example.com
- Replicate it as many times as necessary - now and in the future.

Question - am I liable to have any issues doing things this way?  i.e. will I end up finding that I have to do individual cert installs on each server?  I am something of a newbie when it comes to SSL certs so I would much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have scripted the install process for my wild card certificate on multiple servers.  There isn't anything that I do differently for each server.  Your approach should work.   My scripts:

1. Put the certificate and signing chain in a known location (`/etc/apache/ssl/`)
2. Add the configuration to the SSL virtual host file

---

```
<VirtualHost *:443>    
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.pm
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/chain.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/authority.pem 

    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I used lighttpd not Apache but I guess the differences will be only cosmetic.